# Convert python script which runs a bash script to executable file with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to convert a python script which runs a local bash script
to executable file with Pyinstaller.

My project structure is as following:

```
Project/
|-- bash_script/
|   |-- script.sh
|-- main.py
```

The main.py contains a line which runs the script locally:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('./bash_script/script.sh', shell=True).decode()
```

Now, after converting the main.py to executable file in linux, if I run it
on a different location from where main.py is located, it won't find the script.

I want to add the shell script to the python executable file, so it won't
depend on the script locally, but, I will just have the executable file and
it will eventually run.

I have tried using --add-data flag to pyinstaller converting commend, however it didn't work.

Thanks!

---

Note: I am using the following command:

`pyinstaller --add-data "./bash_script/script.sh:." --onefile main.py`

and I get an error after running in dist dir:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./bash_script/script.sh: not found
```

Comment: According to https://serverfault.com/questions/319115/bash-execute-piped-lines-from-stdin you can pipe a bash script into bash via stdin. So you could embed the bash script as string in a Python script and feed it to bash.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't want to pipeline the result of the executable file, because eventually I want a single executable file which I can run from anywhere and still it will work.

Comment: I meant you should use "subprocess" to run bash in a process and feed the script into **bash's** stdin. This has nothing to do with the stdin or stdout of your executable.

Comment: Oh ok, but how can I do that? because I am calling the bash script inside what I am trying to convert to executable file. Can you maybe elaborate on that? thanks!

Comment: @MichaelButscher I am sorry, forgot to tag you.

Comment: @Chopin  please post the command that you are using to run `pyinstaller`...   using the add-data parameter should be all you need to do

Comment: @Alexander Posted it...

Comment: IM working on an answer

Comment: Basically you can define a variable "script" containing the bash script as bytes object and call `output = subprocess.check_output('bash', input=script, shell=False).decode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.py`:

```
import subprocess
import os

script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'bash_script','script.sh')
output = subprocess.check_output(script, shell=True).decode()
print(output)
```

Then run:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data ./bash_script/script.sh:./bash_script main.py
```

And bobs your uncle!

p.s. `-F` is the same as `--onefile`